# Vim: How to open a file from current directory list without using arrow keys

Tags: vim

Suppose I am editing a file using vim, and I go back to the file's current directory using `:Ex`, and I have a list of all the files I could open, I know arrow keys + `Enter` works, but is there a way to use `: something` to open a specific file? I tried `:e filename` but this goes directly back to the root of vim instead of the current directory.

Thanks.

Comment: `:h autochdir`. This [link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autochdir') might help you

Comment: @paul thanks a lot this is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is not a `:`-command, but it does the job and it can be in the muscle memory already:

You can move around the directory listing just like in a standard buffer. So you can `/filename<Enter>` to get to your file and `<Enter>` to open it. But typing whole `filename` can be rather cumbersome, so let's improve:

If there is something specific in the `filename-baz`, it will be enough to `/baz<Enter><Enter>`. And yet better, if you run vim with `set incsearch` and `set hlsearch` as many do, you'll see the search space narrow down to your `filename`, so you can easily get the prefix-search behavior of file commanders. Or even better, thanks to the coloring.

In case you can see the filename on the screen, then with [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion), you can `<Leader><Leader>w`, then the usually two letters to get there and `<Enter><Enter>`.

Answer (score 3):

> tried :e filename but this goes directly back to the root of vim instead of the current directory.

This may happen because you are running vim from a different directory.

Suppose I run vim from my home directory, you will have to run `:e /path/to/filename` and `:tabe /path/to/filename` where the filepath is relative to the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can open another file while vim is open with `:tabe filename` and to switch to the other file you type `:tabn` or `:tabp` for next and previous accordingly.

Maybe this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27587) can help you

Comment: I just tried, but I think I have to `set asutochdri` before doing that because whenever I `:e filename` or `:tabe filename` it jumps back to the default root directory. Thanks!

Comment: No idea why it always creates a new file when I used  `:tabe filename`..